# Function to create indexes using schema variables

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm currently trying to create a function that will create an index on a table in every schema  in the data warehouse. This is the script I have so far:

```
create or replace function dwh.loan_type_id_indexing()
returns void language plpgsql AS
$PROC$
Declare
       myschema varchar;
               sql text;        
Begin 
    for myschema in 
        SELECT nspname
          FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace 
         where nspname not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_temp_1',
                               'pg_temp_7', 'pg_toast', 'pg_toast_temp_1',
                               'pg_toast_temp_7','public', 'c1', 'dwh',
                               'users', 'c2'
                              )
         order by nspname
    loop        
        sql = 'CREATE INDEX '|| myschema || '_' ||'type_id ON '|| 
        myschema || '.' ||'.fact_tbl USING btree (loan_type_id)';

        execute sql;

    end loop;
END
$PROC$
volatile;
```

I know this isn't correct but it will give you my thought process on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: First, it's a good idea to use `quote_ident()` around `myschema`, though in this case you may know the names don't need quoting.

Comment: Also, you're missing a semicolon on the final `END;` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of filtering out schemas and assuming every other one has the the table you want, query `information_schema` for them and loop over the resulting list:

```
select t.table_schema
from information_schema.tables t inner join information_schema.columns c 
  on (t.table_schema = c.table_schema and t.table_name = c.table_name) 
where t.table_name = 'fact_loan' and c.column_name = 'loan_type_id'
  and t.table_schema NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
  and t.table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema', 'ad_delivery', 'dwh', 'users', 'wand');
```

You now have everything you need to create the index with `EXECUTE` by looping over the records returned from the query.

You might want to `RAISE NOTICE 'Creating index on %s.fact_loan.loan_type_id', table_schema;` to allow you to track progress, too, as index builds can take a while.

If you *were* going to filter schemas, you'd be better off using `schemaname NOT LIKE 'pg_%' AND lower(shemaname) <> 'information_schema'` as shown above.

BTW, I usually find this sort of job more convenient to do from a script outside the database where I have access to multiple connections, threading/multiprocessing, etc. A quick Python script with the `psycopg2` driver for Pg would let you bang something like this together that does the index builds in parallel say 4 at a time; the right number would depend on your disk configuration.